# Stabilising 3d cameras for mapping outdoors - mechanical or programmatic

Tags: computer-vision, gyroscope, stability, ros2

I am preparing to mount Intel Realsense and Zed and Oak-d cameras onto a 4 wheel mobility scooter to do mapping of my local area.

I'm not looking for recommendations but rather an understanding of mechanical and programmatic vibration removal techniques. Terrain will be combination of roads paths and grass.

Comment: May be electronic image stabilization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very tricky problem for vision-based SLAM systems. But if you are using the depth camera just for depth sensing and perception, I guess that might be ignorable under the condition that the exposure time is short enough.

But you still might want to consider some solutions for vibration removal.

Removing the motion blur after it happened is almost meaning less if you are looking for a real-time solution. There are sensors that support HW level stabilization but that is not for your situation if you are using off the shelf depth camera. In all of them, CMOS sensor and lens are fixed on PCB. So you should consider an external stabilizer.

I highly recommend using mechanical vibration dampers like the following.

[Off the shelf damper](https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32829635379.html?gatewayAdapt=Pc2Msite)

Comment: Vibration removal gives me a good start thanks -  (was looking at camera gimbals but they are designed for heavier devices).  As I am mapping rather than driving, post processing is also possible but I will ask a more specific question once I get some data. Many thanaks!

Comment: Yes if it is for mapping passive vibration is mandatory to get a reasonable result. Good luck with your experiment.